# "Multiplex uid mismatch" when trying to get info from Unix socket

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunneling, unix-sockets

I created a unix socket in order to enable SSH multiplexing for my SSH tunnel. I'm new to unix sockets so I wanted to see what this pseudo-file in my filesystem contains. I've tried using:

`nc -U socket.file` and `echo "$(cat socket.file)"`

And in both cases, this error is returned:

`multiplex uid mismatch: peer euid 501 != uid 0`

I'm really just curious and want to `cat` or `tail` this unix socket "file" to see what's returned when I use that SSH tunnel. In the end, I'm trying to understand how communication between machines work using this unix socket "file".

How do I read from this unix socket?

Comment: You will need to give more details on how you are using `ssh`.